# How do grad schools train grad students to be teaching assistants?

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate, teaching-assistant

I am an international student and doing Ph.D. in Physics at a US university.

My teaching assistant (TA) duty is to tutor undergrad students. I am supposed to solve whatever problems undergrads bringing to me. The problem is that I do not know which problems they are having to prepare in advance. Every undergrad from every lab, class in the physics department can bring whatever homework they have to me to ask. Also, I am an International Student and when I was an undergrad, I did not use the textbook undergrad here in US use and many problems are totally strange to me. Sometimes I cannot solve their homework problems. I felt very embarrassed and sorry since I wasted their time, sitting there for 15 -20 minutes to wait for me to solve it.

I am not a terribly bad student, I consistently perform about 80 percent for all the courses as well as standard exams like GRE Physics. But I feel like I am not smart enough to pursue a Ph.D. Sometimes I can come up with very good solutions for grad problems but I am not a fast thinker to solve some undergrad problems which might be solved in a very simple way.

Do grad schools train grad students to be teaching assistants? I think the Ph.D. students need to be prepared to do good TA jobs, isn't it? For example, if someone teaches labs, they should know the content of the lab for that day to come in preparation? How can I become a better TA given my described task?

Comment: Do you prepare for your office hours? e.g. by going through the homework that they are supposed to do on your own beforehand?

Comment: the problem is that I don't know which homework they supposed to have. Every undergrads from every lab can come to ask

Comment: @oldman " undergrad from every lab, class in the physics department can bring whatever homework they have to me to ask." Does that mean that undergrads could potentially bring you questions about E&M and special relativity in the same office hours and you'd be expected to answer them?? Forgive me, but that sounds borderline insane. I'm not sure that most faculty could solve *all* problems that quickly.

Comment: @chipbuster yes, it is exactly what I mean. They can bring either Mechanics, E&M, wave, relativity or whatever in my office hour. I think the organization in my department is completely a mess. But If I am smarter, I should be able to handle the undergrad problems.

Comment: Do you think you would have an easier time of it if the students came with an existing answer that you could critique? Although it would certainly be helpful to offer guidance if you know how to solve the problems at hand, it might not be strictly necessary, or even the best way to tutor a student.

Comment: @oldman I'm no expert, but I'm starting to think that you're not the problem here. There's a reason we don't expect professors to randomly give lectures on any subject in the curriculum on a one-hour notice--there's a difference between having taken a class in something and having it fresh enough to be able to teach it........

Have you tried asking other TAs in the department how they handle it?

Comment: @BryanKrause yes I do.  Students tend to spend about 15-20 minutes and they need their problems to be solved fast. And as I said, some problems are totally strange to me, so I find it is very hard to give them the guidance while I myself still think how to solve that

Comment: @chipbuster  I asked 1 or 2 people and they said all the problems were easy and that I am a grad student, I need to be able to solve undergrad problems. I don't think they will confess the truth. I am not arrogant but my department ranking is about 400 and given my 80 percent for GRE physics, I think my background is better than some grad students here, and If I cannot solve, then it might happen with others also.

Comment: @chipbuster: But this sounds similar to an open "math lab" situation, where TAs have hours and are on tap to answer any possible questions on undergraduate mathematics -- and exists at every institution I've been part of.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this concept. Would you usually have multiple TAs at such a lab?

Comment: @chipbuster: Yes, that's true; likely multiple staff members at once -- and if one is better a particular topic then they likely field it. (For what it's worth, if you web-search "math lab", then you'll find lots of hits at U.S. colleges; quite likely one at your institution.)

Comment: @chipbuster: We do have 2 TAs at once also. But the guy on task with me do nothing and so rude that no one wants to ask him. So I am the only person helping students during the office hours.

Comment: "to tutor undergrad students" and "I am supposed to solve whatever problems undergrads bringing to me" contradict each other, I'd say...

Answer (score 6):

How do grad schools train teaching assistants?
Some graduate programs offer specific workshops to teach the fundamentals of teaching. However, being a good TA usually comes down to 3 things:

- Proper understanding of the material
- Experience in teaching beforehand (I am a much better TA now compared to a few years ago)
- Preparation (this is necessary even if you are experienced)

**Nonetheless**, the content of your actual question (and corresponding comments) is quite worrisome. It is absolutely not the responsibility of a TA to be prepared to answer any question from students of every lab, especially without previous preparation. I would dare to say this is not even the responsibility of the professor teaching the course. I have yet to meet a professor who doesn't feel the need for previous preparation when teaching a course for the tenth time, nevermind teaching new courses for the first time.

Answer (score 4):

From what I see, no one actually trains TAs. There may be a workshop or two that will tell you to be consistent when grading and to not get into unnecessarily close relationships with students, but that's it.

As for your particular situation, I find it weird that you have to solve whatever problems students bring you; perhaps, you're misunderstanding your duties. First, students are supposed to do their homework themselves. Second, you cannot possibly know the contents of all courses. I'd imagine that your actual duties are: 1) if you know the material the student is asking about, you help them navigate through it but you do not solve the problems for them; 2) if you don't know the material, you send the student to some other TA. Anyway, try speaking to other TAs about these issues, they'll likely give you some advice.

Comment: I would add a third, possibly more likely duty: To help the student find the resource they need to learn how to solve their problem. These are usually the sorts of skills that grad students have already mastered to some degree, and often have little to do with the content of a particular course.